# How to use ternary operator in the render method in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to render two buttons based on some state condition using ternary operator just to avoid code repetition.

**What I am trying to do?**

I have two buttons Cancel and Start based on state value `load_cancel`. If Cancel button clicked `load_cancel` set to `true` and when `load_cancel` set to `false` Start button is displayed. So I have something like this in the `render` method

```
{props.item_id && this.props.load_cancel &&
    <button onClick= 
        {this.props.handle_load_start}>start</button>}
{props.item_id && !this.props.load_cancel  &&
    <button onClick={this.props.handle_load_cancel}>Cancel</button>}
```

How do I do the same using ternary operator?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this

```
prop.item_id ? (
  this.props.load_cancel ? (
    <button onClick={this.props.handle_load_start}>start</button>
  ) : (
    <button onClick={this.props.handle_load_cancel}>Cancel</button>
  )
) : null
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check `this.props.load_cancel` and if it's true render the start button otherwise render the cancel button

```
{props.item_id && (this.props.load_cancel? <button onClick= 
        {this.props.handle_load_start}>start</button> :
    <button onClick={this.props.handle_load_cancel}>Cancel</button>)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

`const { item_id, load_cancel } = this.props;
 const button = item_id ? (
     <button onClick={this.handleClick}>{load_cancel ? 'Start' : 'Cancel'}</button>
) : null;`

And in handleClick you cand either call `this.props.handle_load_start` or `this.props.handle_load_cancel` depending on your props.
This way you only write jsx for button once.